# Can I export cookies from python to Chrome?

Tags: python, cookies, sqlite, python-requests, pywin32

Here's what I'm trying to do.
I want to read the cookies from Chrome's sqlite file, use them on python and then save them again to Chrome's sqlite file since they could have been updated while using them with python.

This is more or less the code I have to test this, I can extract them and use them correctly but I can't manage to update them on sqlite and keep using them on the browser.

I'm not even sure if I'm using the correct types or if I'm passing the correct type to the UPDATE, should I do anything to newEncrypted before passing it to sqlite?

- encrypted_value's type() is buffer
- decrypted's type() is unicode
- newEncrypted's type() is str

  ```
  import shutil, cookielib, sqlite3, win32crypt

  def decrypt(result):
      cookies = []

      for host_key,name,value,expires_utc,encrypted_value in result:
          #print "Adding cookie"
          if value == '':
              print encrypted_value
              decrypted = win32crypt.CryptUnprotectData(encrypted_value, None, None, None, 0)[1].decode('utf-8')
          else:
              decrypted = value


          cookies.append(cookielib.Cookie(None, name, decrypted, '80', True, host_key, True, False, '/', True, False, (int(expires_utc)/1000000)-11644473600, False, None, None, None, False))

      return cookies

  cookie_file = "C:/Users/Daviid/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default/Cookies"

  conn = sqlite3.connect(cookie_file)
  cursor = conn.cursor()

  sql = 'select host_key,name,value,expires_utc,encrypted_value from cookies where host_key = ".google.com" or host_key = "www.google.com"'
  cursor.execute(sql)

  result = cursor.fetchall()[0]
  cookies = decrypt(result)

  ###
  # Use Cookies in urllib, Requests, whatever...
  # cookies get updated
  ###
  updatedCookie = cookies[0]
  updatedCookie.value = "NewValue"

  newEncrypted = win32crypt.CryptProtectData(updatedCookie.value, '', None, None, None, 0)
  cursor.execute("UPDATE cookies SET encrypted_value=? WHERE host_key = ? AND name = ?",(newEncrypted, updatedCookie.domain, updatedCookie.name))

  cursor.close()
  conn.commit()
  conn.close()
  ```

Comment: Hmm, are you trying to develop some software that connects *Chrome* to some funky sites, and leave no traces that the user could spot?

Comment: @CristiFati no, just trying to automate a web based game

Answer (score 1):

*sqlite* documentation page: [[Python]: sqlite3 - DB-API 2.0 interface for SQLite databases](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#module-sqlite3).

*code.py*:

```
import sys
import sqlite3
import win32crypt


COOKIE_FILE = "ChromeCookies.db"
HOST_KEYS = ".google.com", "www.google.com"


def decrypt_cookies(query_result):
    cookies = []
    for host_key, name, value, expires_utc, encrypted in query_result:
        if encrypted:
            decrypted_descr, decrypted = win32crypt.CryptUnprotectData(encrypted, None, None, None, 0)
        else:
            decrypted_descr, decrypted = u"", u""
        cookies.append((host_key, name, expires_utc, decrypted, decrypted_descr, value))
        # Idx:              0       1        2           3            4            5
    return cookies


def init_db(file_name=COOKIE_FILE):
    conn = sqlite3.connect(file_name)
    return conn, conn.cursor()


def shutdown_db(cursor, connection, commit=False):
    cursor.close()
    if commit:
        connection.commit()
    connection.close()


def get_cookies(cursor, host_keys=HOST_KEYS):
    query_tmpl = "SELECT host_key, name, value, expires_utc, encrypted_value FROM cookies WHERE host_key IN {:}"
    cursor.execute(query_tmpl.format(host_keys))
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    cookies = decrypt_cookies(result)
    return cookies


def format_long_text(text, max_len=50):
    length = len(text)
    if length <= max_len:
        format_string = "({:d})[{:s}]"
    else:
        format_string =  "({:d})[{:s}...]"
    return format_string.format(length, text[:max_len])


def print_cookie(idx, cookie_tuple, print_data=False):
    print("\nIdx: {:d}\nHost key: {:s}\nName: {:s}\nExpires: {:d}".format(idx, *(cookie_tuple[:3])))
    if print_data:
         print("Decrypted: {:s}".format(format_long_text(cookie_tuple[3])))
         print("Decrypted description: {:s}".format(format_long_text(cookie_tuple[4])))
         print("Data: {:s}".format(format_long_text(cookie_tuple[5])))


def update_cookie(cursor, cookie_tuple):
    decrypted_length = len(cookie_tuple[3])
    encrypted = win32crypt.CryptProtectData(cookie_tuple[3][:decrypted_length // 2], cookie_tuple[4], None, None, None, 0)
    cursor.execute("UPDATE cookies SET encrypted_value = ? WHERE host_key = ? AND name = ?", (buffer(encrypted), cookie_tuple[0], cookie_tuple[1]))


def main():
    conn, cursor = init_db()
    cookies = get_cookies(cursor)
    cookie_idx = 8 % len(cookies) # For simplicity's sake choose an index that references a cookie with an unique `host_key` and `name`
    for idx, cookie_tuple in enumerate(cookies):
        print_cookie(idx, cookie_tuple)
    updated_cookie = cookies[cookie_idx]
    print_cookie(cookie_idx, updated_cookie, print_data=True)
    update_cookie(cursor, updated_cookie)
    shutdown_db(cursor, conn, commit=True)

    print("\nReopening DB...\n")

    conn, cursor = init_db()
    cookies = get_cookies(cursor)
    print("Cookies: {:d}".format(len(cookies)))
    #for idx, cookie_tuple in enumerate(cookies):
    #    print_cookie(idx, cookie_tuple)
    updated_cookie = cookies[cookie_idx]
    print_cookie(cookie_idx, updated_cookie, print_data=True)
    shutdown_db(cursor, conn)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} on {:s}\n".format(sys.version, sys.platform))
    main()
```

**Notes**:

- I split the code in functions to be more modular (reusable and parameterized)
- I don't have *cookielib* installed, so I removed all the parts that reference it, and using tuples to store cookies data instead (I know that `dict` or `collections.namedtuple` would have been nicer, but I didn't want to add more code, as this part won't be kept anyway)
- No error handling
- Some of the functions are for printing purposes only
- As a test, I chose one of the cookies and I only keep the 1<sup>st</sup> half of its (encrypted) data. It will become invalid of course, but it's just for demo purposes only
- **The key is `buffer(encrypted)` (in `update_cookie`), since the `cookies.encrypted_value` column is a `BLOB`**
- It's *Python2* compatible **only** (noticed `#print "Adding cookie"` in the question), because in *Python3* strings are unicode (and `buffer` is not present)

**Output**:

> ```
> (py27x64_test) e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q050886719>"e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py27x64_test\Scripts\python.exe" code.py
> Python 2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 20:53:40) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>
>
> Idx: 0
> Host key: .google.com
> Name: 1P_JAR
> Expires: 13176376602000000
>
> Idx: 1
> Host key: .google.com
> Name: AID
> Expires: 13194604800101431
>
> Idx: 2
> Host key: .google.com
> Name: APISID
> Expires: 13236602265411651
>
> Idx: 3
> Host key: .google.com
> Name: CGIC
> Expires: 13189118241681530
>
> Idx: 4
> Host key: .google.com
> Name: CGIC
> Expires: 13189118241681619
>
> Idx: 5
> Host key: .google.com
> Name: CONSENT
> Expires: 13791196798240053
>
> Idx: 6
> Host key: .google.com
> Name: GMAIL_RTT
> Expires: 0
>
> Idx: 7
> Host key: .google.com
> Name: HSID
> Expires: 13236602265411610
>
> Idx: 8
> Host key: .google.com
> Name: NID
> Expires: 13189336603638418
>
> Idx: 9
> Host key: .google.com
> Name: SAPISID
> Expires: 13236602265411673
>
> Idx: 10
> Host key: .google.com
> Name: SID
> Expires: 13236602265411550
>
> Idx: 11
> Host key: .google.com
> Name: SIDCC
> Expires: 13181563951325551
>
> Idx: 12
> Host key: .google.com
> Name: SNID
> Expires: 13189336552795314
>
> Idx: 13
> Host key: .google.com
> Name: SSID
> Expires: 13236602265411631
>
> Idx: 14
> Host key: .google.com
> Name: TAID
> Expires: 13174995823101361
>
> Idx: 15
> Host key: www.google.com
> Name: GAPS
> Expires: 13229834000111924
>
> Idx: 8
> Host key: .google.com
> Name: NID
> Expires: 13189336603638418
> Decrypted: (254)[132=tqLTXZ4dOSPbstdv6oktg9VxbNX3LpwLKGpXzpMwnyVTis...]
> Decrypted description: (0)[]
> Data: (0)[]
>
> Reopening DB...
>
> Cookies: 16
>
> Idx: 8
> Host key: .google.com
> Name: NID
> Expires: 13189336603638418
> Decrypted: (127)[132=tqLTXZ4dOSPbstdv6oktg9VxbNX3LpwLKGpXzpMwnyVTis...]
> Decrypted description: (0)[]
> Data: (0)[]
> ```

Comment: Did this anser your question?

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late reply I never found free time to test it and ended up forgetting about it.
For my case it doesn't work because, I believe, Chrome's Cookies file is always being used by Chrome, so I get "sqlite3.OperationalError: disk I/O error"

I've tried copying the file, modifying and then overwriting but it doesn't work. I've also tried using sqlite isolation_level = "exclusive" but I still get the same error.

I used your code and made a class.
https://pastebin.com/khEWqhR2